# Issue with including changes from a previous branch in the current pull request after merging another branch in Git

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I'm facing an issue while working with Git. I followed these steps:

1. Create a new brunch B1 `git switch -c B1` changing a file in the project `git add . && git commit -m "B1"` `git push origin B1`. Create pull request in GitHub(B1)
2. Create a new brunch B2 `git switch -c B2` changing a file in the project `git add . && git commit -m "B2"` `git push origin B2`. Create pull request in GitHub(B2)
3. Merged the pull request of branch B1. On GitHub I click "create a merge commit"
   HEAD is on the last commit in B2
4. Pulled changes into branch B2 using rebase: `git pull origin main --rebase` or `git rebase main`. Head pointer pointer is set to commit in B2
5. Pushed my branch to the remote server: `git push origin B2`

   `![rejected]        B2 -> B2 (non-fast-forward)`

   `error: failed to push some refs`

If I follow the instructions `git pull origin B2` and `git push origin B2`. I noticed that commits from branch B1 are included in my pull request for branch B2. How can I avoid including changes from B1 in the pull request for B2 after merging B1 into main?

The idea is to understand how to use git with a rebase strategy.

[upd]: as an option I can use `git push origin B2 --force` in this article https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Any advice or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest to use `git push origin B2 --force`. Is it official practice? I thought --force flag it is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your step 4 was wrong. You should have said `pull` without `--rebase` (this code assumes your HEAD is B2):

```
git pull origin main
```

Or even better, you could have rebased B2 onto main (this code assumes your HEAD is B2):

```
git fetch
git rebase main
```

Basically what you did was to rebase the new part of main onto B2. That's exactly backwards. The new part of main is the commits from B1, so now you've added B1 onto the end of B2, as you have rightly observed.

Another possibility, best of all in my opinion, would be to omit step 4 entirely. That's what I would have done. If you are about to push B2 into a pull request and you do not anticipate any merge conflicts, your step 4 gains you exactly nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried following the instructions and it leads to the same result. Maybe a forced click is the only option? I update the post added more details

Comment: Regarding the second option (skipping step 4 entirely), in a large project, it would be helpful to sync your changes with the main branch from time to time. This is because code in the main branch can affect your changes without conflicts. But I agree it is good option.

Comment: Any time you rebase something that has already been pushed, you will have to use force to push it again later. That's a given. But nowhere in your question did you say that B2 had to be pushed twice. Perhaps your description of the situation is incomplete or inaccurate. Anyway I stand by my answer, based on the situation you described. What you have _now_ I have no idea.

Comment: Absolutely! @matt may be worth adding the sentence "Any time you release something that has already been pushed, you will have to use force to push it again later." As part of your answer? Then it will be complete I apologize for the ambiguity